# Why does visual studio requires debug enabled to run localhost for php webb application

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know why visual studio code has to be running php debug in order to display the webb application correctly in localhost? I have set up a test site in IIS which is a php webb application. I edit and debug that site in Visual Studio Code. But in order to run that site in locahost VS Code has to be running with debug enabled? I dont get why.....

Comment: Have you configured a web site in IIS or you're just relying on Visual Studio Code to do the whole thing?

Comment: Yes I have congigured a website in IIS

Comment: What happens exactly when you request the site in the browser and Code isn't running?

Comment: If I request a php page on that site there is this spinning wheel like its being loaded (but its not) and it doesnt load until I start debug session in VS Code for the very same site

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're requesting the page in debug mode. When you do so, Xdebug attempts to connect to your debug client (Visual Studio Code or whatever tool that's listening to the configured port, typically 9000).

The easiest way to control this is to install a browser extension that:

- Sets or unsets the appropriate cookies
- Displays an icon to enable/disable debugging

I use [Xdebug Helper for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/xdebug-helper-for-firefox/) and [Xdebug Helper for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc) but there're surely more extensions to pick from.

[image: Xdebug Helper for Firefox]